# Ask to user credentials to access Google Drive Api

Tags: python, google-drive-api, github-actions

I'm creating a cli tool to move file around in a user Google Drive space. I'm using Python and Google Drive Api Python SDK to do that and I've created [this repo](https://github.com/Daniele-Tentoni/py-gdrive-file-mover).

Now I have to run every midnight this tool to move file from a folder to another with input from user. Locally I can create credentials.son and retrieve credentials from it, generate the token.json file and use it to authenticate to Drive api. But in public CI environment, I would save my credentials in a Github Secret and give them to my tool at runtime using an option.

1. Can I do that?
2. There's some security issues?

I would publish this tool in some forums (like Python SubReddit) to get suggesstions and improvements, but before do that, I'd like to make this move file function as complete as possible.